# Export C function name to DLL/SO with special chars using Gcc

Tags: c, gcc, dll, compilation, linker

Is there any way to export a function to a shared library using special characters with Gcc in a native manner without ad hoc data structure?

For example, I need to export "LibraryExportFunc" with the name"library-export-func" and then read back by another program using dlopen/dlsym.

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to modify the function name or add a wrapper function to the library?

Comment: In gcc, there is an `__asm__` progma for such renaming, eg `int LibraryExportFunc(void) __asm__ ("library-export-func");`

Comment: And in MSVC you have `.def` files to give explicit names to exports.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I'm sorry but it doesn't work. This is the error message: /tmp/ccufRCB1.s:70: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `-'. It work if  I use underscore but It's not what I want.

@dbush I'm writing this library so I can modify the function name. 

@blindy I must use GCC for compatibility with Unix/Libux.

Comment: Using a `-` in the symbol name seems like a bad idea, as in pretty much every programming language this is the minus operator.

Comment: @BrechtSanders I need the **-** because I'm implementing a Lisp like language where this char is commonly used in symbol names. I want to access directly to the function with dlsym instead of using a lookup table or a conversion function.

Comment: @Tommy Sadly, you're right, even the Assembler doesn't accept these dash characters in a symbol-name.